# Show error shortcut

Tags: visual-studio

I have an error in my code as shown in picture. I can see this error when I move with mouse over it. How to make the same with short key? What is show error short key?

> [image]

IDE is Visual Studio 2012

Comment: C# is language, IDE is Visual Studio. Those things got nothing to do with the language you choose to write in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio there is a window called `Error List` you can show it By using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or in menu `View --> Error List`.

> [image]

Comment: Plus one for answering on absolutely minimal information on the part of the OP.

Comment: yeah, this is the only way to show compiler errors if you are not using the mouse.

Comment: Took the liberty to add a screenshot I was going to use myself, hope it's fine.

Comment: Strange, in my system it is CTRL+\+E. Why?

Comment: CTRL+\+E. in `VS 2015`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're talking about the big exception window that pops up when your application throws an exception, then this isn't quite the same.

Exceptions caught and displayed in the exception viewer are **runtime errors**, this is not a runtime error.

Instead, you can see these errors in the **Error List**, go to View -> Error List (Ctrl+W, E)